# Tannaka duality for closed monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I asked this some time ago at [mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277069/tannaka-duality-for-closed-monoidal-categories), and people there explained to me the mathematical part of what I was asking, but the question about references remains open. In my impression, people here at MO are more active, so I hope, specialists in the category theory could clarify the remaining part of my question. (At the same time I foresee that somebody can suggest another idea of how this can be proved, and I would welcome this as well.)

The [nLab article on the Tannaka duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tannaka+duality#idea) says that this theory was generalized to monoids in arbitrary [closed monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category) (symmetric and complete in some sense):

> if we take a monoid $A$ in such a category $\mathcal V$ and consider the category $_A{\mathcal V}$ of all left modules over $A$, then $A$ can be recovered from $_A{\mathcal V}$ as the object of enriched endomorphisms of the forgetful functor $F: {_A{\mathcal V}}\to {\mathcal V}$.

(As far as I understand, this result is called a reconstruction theorem.)

Some details in this construction are however explained at nLab vaguely, in particular,

> how is the structure of the enriched category introduced on $_A{\mathcal V}$?

Can anybody give me a link to a text where this result is explained accurately so that I could refer to it with a clear conscience? (Perhaps I am missing something, I do not see where this is written. From what I see, I have the impression that this is folklore, but I have no confidence, and I do not dare to write this in my paper.)

Answer (score 2):

I think a good reference for your question would be R. Street, *Quantum Groups, A Path to Current Algebra*, Chapter 16: *Tannaka Duality* (see [here](https://books.google.be/books?redir_esc=y&id=u0slIpdBjYUC&q=tannaka#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: I am reading this. This is strange, why don't they want to formulate this result explicitly, as a theorem?